# Hide/Show a Panel depending on a CheckBox in Wicket

Tags: java, checkbox, wicket

I have this piece of code:

```
final WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
container.setVisible(aBooleanValue);
container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
container.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
add(container);

final CheckBox hideContainer = new CheckBox("hideContainer", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(getModel(), "hideContainer"));
container.add(hideContainer);
hideContainer.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(getModelObject().getHideContainer())) {
            container.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            container.setVisible(true);
        }
        target.addComponent(MyForm.this.get("container"));
        
    }
});
```

Which creates a WebMarkupContainer and a Checkbox, if the checkbox is checked then the container should be hidden, if the checkbox is not checked, then the container should be visible.

But this doesn't work... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed if `onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)` is called when you check the box?

Comment: It should be sufficient to call target.add(container);

Comment: For checkboxes you should use "click" event, on IE "change" will not fire until the checkbox loses the focus.

Comment: The onUpdate is being called for sure with the "onchange" event. I have tried with the "onclick" and it doesn't work either. About IE, it doesn't matter, we use Firefox and the users of our webapp too.

Comment: Changeing visibility of components: http://wicketguide.comsysto.com/guide/chapter5.html#chapter5_1

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [AjaxCheckBox](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxCheckBox.html). Override `onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget)` method and move code from behavior, as it should work correctly on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

A best wicket practice is to configure wicket components to pull data rather than pushing data to them. Instead of setting the visibility of the component can you please try to override the isVisible method of the component.

final WebMarkupContainer container = new WebMarkupContainer("container"){

```
   public boolean isVisible(){
      return showContainer;//showContainer is a boolean instance variable
   }
```

};

And in the onchange event change the showContainer value and add the component to target.